# How to get the right \baselinskip in the annotation with authortitle-dw and smaller font

Tags: biblatex, fontsize, line-spacing, biblatex-dw

If I change the font size of the annotations in my bibliography the size changes but the baseline skip doesn’t. I know that TeX uses the last font in a paragraph to calculate the baseline skip, but I don’t know how I can fix this problem.

At this image it’s obvious that the annotations is set with a too big skip.

[image: problem with baseline skip]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
   backend=biber,
   style=authortitle-dw,
   annotation=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% extreme values make the problem obvious
\renewcommand{\annotationfont}{\scriptsize}
\usepackage[textwidth=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\nocite{bertram}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I tried to set the annotation with a `\parbox` with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{%
   \par\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}
   \parbox{\textwidth}{\annotationfont #1\addperiod}.
}
```

but this leads to an extra period that I can’t delete. Furthermor it seems like a bad hack to me …
(I made `\annotationfont` red for the next image to make the extra period visible.)

[image: extra period]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a superfluous `\finentry` command in `biblatex-dw`’s (re)definition of the bibmacro `finentry`. If you delete that and put a `\par` into the `DeclareFieldFormat` command, it works. I have altered your example accordingly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[%
   backend=biber,
   style=authortitle-dw,
   annotation=true,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% extreme values make the problem obvious
\renewcommand{\annotationfont}{\scriptsize}
\usepackage[textwidth=3cm]{geometry}

\DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}{%
   \annotationfont #1\addperiod\par}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldundef{annotation}}
    and
    test {\iffieldundef{library}}
  }
    {\finentry}
    {\iffieldundef{library}
      {}
      {\ifbool{bbx:library}
        {\setunit{\addperiod\par}
         \printfield{library}}
        {}}%
     \iffieldundef{annotation}
      {}
      {\ifbool{bbx:annotation}
        {\iffieldundef{library}
           {\setunit{\addperiod\par}}
           {}
         \printfield{annotation}}
        {}}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{bertram,springer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I will take care to make this more robust in future releases of biblatex-dw, so that a simple redefinition of the `\annotationfont` macro will have the desired effect.

**Edit:**
I improved the redefinition of the bibmacro `finentry`, so that it now also works if the fields `library` and `annotation` are both defined.

Comment: Thank you! It even works if I leave out the `\printtext{\par}` in `\renewbibmacro*{finentry}` since this one doubles the `\par` of `\DeclareFieldFormat{annotation}`, I guess.

Comment: @Tobi, thanks for pointing to this, I just forgot to delete it after trying some things out.

Comment: Ah, OK. I just discovered that `\printtext{\par}` causes a blank line between the bib entries even if `\bibitemsep` is set to `0pt`.

Comment: @Tobi, do you still have a blank line with my edited code?

Comment: The new solution works as expected :-)